# Impossible to build a project with xCode 9 after update - Could not build module

Tags: xcode, build, module, updates

Yesterday, I compiled my Swift / Cpp project with xCode 8 (last release) and everything worked well. This morning, xCode performed the v9 update (with Swift 4) and my project stoped to compile. I have the following type of error :

```
/opt/local/include/unctrl.h:60:63: Unknown type name 'SCREEN'
[CompletePath]/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: Could not build module 'Darwin'
[CompletePath]/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
[CompletePath]/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Headers/AppKit.h:10:9: Could not build module 'Foundation'
```

I tried to disable modules enabling, but it doesn't change anything.

xCode doesn't allow me to update the project to Swift 4, it says the project needs to compile to be update, so I selected xCode 3.2 version in project settings. I'm still on OS X 10.12.

Comment: i'm also facing same problem did you solved this?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the only way I found to fix the issue was to uprgade the project to Swift 4. I used the manual method for that: I changed the language from Swift 3 to Swift 4 in project settings and I corrected all compiling errors by hand, until the project recompiled well. It's maybe not the best solution but it worked.